# Mantain aspect-ratio inside a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a squared button that matches the height of `object`

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f533;
}

.object {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #2ecaac;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="object"></div>
  <button class="button" type="button">
        button
    </button>
</div>
```

But in the result the aspect-ratio is ignored. How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like it's working for me... https://codepen.io/chase-mortensen/pen/QWaQvLd

Comment: @chase try separate the in-line div, https://codepen.io/lilkimo/pen/ZEvrKPV

Comment: I believe `aspect-ratio` only works when you specify one of `height` or `width`. So if you were to set the `height` of the `button` to `150px` (like the `.object`), it would work. But the `stretch` doesn't set the `height` in a way usable by `aspect-ratio`. Might be worth throwing a bug at Chromium's bug tracker (or whatever browser you see it in).